# Two image in tkinter using PhotoImage

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I'm making a program that is using 2 different images. I have loading page which is just a picture called 'loading.png' which works fine.

When I try and add a different image called 'table.png', using the same method, onto a different window it doesn't display but on the intro window it displays the image I want.

This is the loading screen code

```
win=Tk()
win.title('PokerChamp')
win.geometry('400x200')

background_image = PhotoImage(file='loading.png')
background_label = Label(win, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

This works fine but when I add this code it displays the wrong image and the main window's image doesn't show.

```
root=Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.config(bg='#1b800b')
root.title('PokerChamp')

image = PhotoImage(file='table.ppm')
label = Label(win, image=image)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why have you attached lyrics to a song?

Comment: It's wrong to have two instance of `TK` check this one out http://effbot.org/tag/Tkinter.Toplevel. Sorry for the initial attachement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, like @AD WAN said, it is incorrect to have to instances of `Tk()`. Second of all, when you initiate the second image, you put it in the first one, `win`, instead of `root`.

This would be your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
win=Tk()
win.title('PokerChamp')
win.geometry('400x200')

background_image = PhotoImage(file='loading.png')
background_label = Label(win, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root=Toplevel()

#root.config(bg='#1b800b')
root.title('PokerChamp')

image = PhotoImage(file='table.ppm')
label = Label(root, image=image)
label.place(relx=0, rely=0)
```

Hope this helps!